# Realizing a wizard in Angular: What is the best approach?

Tags: angular

I want to realize a wizard in Angular, that is, a step to step navigation page with next and back buttons. Furthermore, the next button should be enabled or disabled depending on what the user chooses on the current page. My current solution is to give an array of TemplateRefs to the wizard which I render with a .

Minimal example:

wizard.component.ts

```
export class WizardComponent {
    @Input() pages!: TemplateRef<any>[];
    @Output() confirmEvent = new EventEmitter<void>();

    currentPage = 0;

    pageBack() {
        this.currentPage -= 1;
    }

    pageForward() {
        if (this.currentPage != this.pages.length) this.currentPage += 1;
        else this.confirmEvent.emit();
    }

}
```

wizard.component.html

```
...
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="pages[currentPage]" />
...
```

The problem is that like this, I cannot emit an event from the page (in the ng-container) to the wizard to make the next button enabled.

Is there a better approach with which I have access to the child (the page)?

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use `<ng-content>` instead of template outlets. Then you could use `@ContentChildren` to get references to the pages within the wizard component.

Comment: But how do I then only render one component at a time?

Comment: I would expect the parent component to be responsible to managing that. I think it's reasonable to build something like this with at least 2 layers of components.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [component](https://ng.ant.design/components/steps/en#components-steps-demo-step-next) or [this](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview).

You can also check the implementation (it's open source) and do the same. You pass step components with a content for each page. Then most likely they are selected by @ContentChildren(WizardStepComponent) and then only 1 is visible depending on the activePage index, while the others are hidden.

The implementation is here: https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/steps/steps.component.ts